# How to fit an image in to screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this xml code ,i want to fit an image to full screen size,i have this code ,but i dint get what i need.Can anybody help me? i am new to android ,any other possible ways to do this? help me please

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.first,
        R.drawable.second,
        R.drawable.third,
        R.drawable.fourth,
        R.drawable.fifth,
        R.drawable.sixth
};
```

Comment: I have also tried different scaleType methods, but it not works,

Comment: **Where** do you set the picture? You forgot `android:src="@drawable/your_picture"`

Comment: Use `android:background="@drawable/pic"`

Comment: I am doing a slideshow  of images using viewpager,

Comment: Please indicate what you got from this code that was not intended, not just what you would like to have because a million things could be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this :

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Its used if want to the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you have your image pulled into the project. Afterwards you want to set the source image with the tag

```
android:src="(name of image)"
```

Then remove,

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

this will allow Android to stretch and skew your drawable image to the appropriate size of the ImageView instead of maintaining aspect ratio within the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

**adjustViewBounds if true will adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
So your image will not stretch to fit XY.** **Go through** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getAdjustViewBounds%28%29

**Remove this line** 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"

**and add this**
android:background="@drawable/yourImage"

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);